# Correct me the Recovery function in MQL5 for MetaTester

Tags: function, recovery, mql5

I wrote a function that increases lot (lotmultiplier) after every losing trade. It increases lot until previous level of maxbalance, earned by expert, is reached. Then it decreases lot to normal. If the expert shows more profitable trades than losing trades and these losing trades don't follow one another, the balance curve emerges from drawdown. That's the plot of the function.
My function increases lot but in MetaTester in doesn't decreases it. So, where is my mistake?

```
`    
double lot()  
{  
double minlot=SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_VOLUME_MIN);  
double maxlot=SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_VOLUME_MAX);  
double lots;  

if(!recovery) lots = NormalizeDouble(minlot, 2);  
if(recovery)  
 {  
  if(LastClosedCountPoints()>=0 && Profit()==MaxBalance()) lots=NormalizeDouble(minlot, 2);  
  else if(LastClosedCountPoints()>0 && Profit()<MaxBalance()) lots=NormalizeDouble(LastClosedDealLot(), 2);   
  else if(LastClosedCountPoints()<0 && Profit()<MaxBalance()) lots=NormalizeDouble(LastClosedDealLot()*recoverylotmultiplier, 2);  
}  

if(lots>maxlot) lots = NormalizeDouble(maxlot, 2);  
if(lots<minlot) lots = NormalizeDouble(minlot, 2);  
return(lots);
}  
`
The function of P/L points counting.  
`  
double LastClosedCountPoints()  
{  
 double price;  
 datetime time;  
 string symbol;  
 ulong ticket;  
 long type;  
 long id;  
 long mg;  
 double lastpoints=0;  
 uint total=HistoryDealsTotal();  

 HistorySelect(0,TimeCurrent());  
 for(int i=0; i<total; i++)  
  {  
   if((ticket=HistoryDealGetTicket(i))>0)  
    {  
     price=HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket,DEAL_PRICE);  
     time=(datetime)HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_TIME);  
     symbol=HistoryDealGetString(ticket,DEAL_SYMBOL);  
     id=HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_POSITION_ID);  
     mg=HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_MAGIC);  
     ENUM_DEAL_TYPE type=(ENUM_DEAL_TYPE)HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_TYPE);  
     ENUM_DEAL_ENTRY in_out=HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_ENTRY);  
     if(price && time && symbol==_Symbol && mg==magic && in_out==DEAL_ENTRY_OUT)  
      {  
       lastpoint=HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket,DEAL_PROFIT)/HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket,DEAL_VOLUME);  
      }  
    }  
  }  
 return(NormalizeDouble(lastpoints, 0));  
}  
`  
The function of the last history deal lot definition.  
`  
double LastClosedDealLot()  
 {  
  double price;  
  datetime time;  
  string symbol;  
  ulong ticket;  
  long type;  
  long id;  
  long mg;  
  double lastlot;  
  uint total=HistoryDealsTotal();  
  
  HistorySelect(0,TimeCurrent());  
  
  for(int j=0; j<total; j++)  
   {  
    if((ticket=HistoryDealGetTicket(j))>0)  
     {  
      price=HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket,DEAL_PRICE);  
      time=(datetime)HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_TIME);  
      symbol=HistoryDealGetString(ticket,DEAL_SYMBOL);  
      id=HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_POSITION_ID);  
      mg=HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_MAGIC);  
      ENUM_DEAL_TYPE type=(ENUM_DEAL_TYPE)HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_TYPE);  
      ENUM_DEAL_ENTRY in_out=HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_ENTRY);  
      if(price && time && symbol==_Symbol && mg==magic && in_out==DEAL_ENTRY_IN)  
       {  
        lastlot=HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket,DEAL_VOLUME);  
       }  
     }  
   }  
  return(NormalizeDouble(lastlot,2));  
 }  
`
The function of definition of the max balance in history, earned by the expert.  
`  
double MaxBalance()  
 {  
  double price;  
  datetime time;  
  string symbol;  
  ulong ticket;  
  long type;  
  long id;  
  long mg;  
  double maxsofar = 0;  
  double maxendinghere = 0;  
  uint total=HistoryDealsTotal();  
  double profit[];  
  ArrayResize(profit, total);  
  ArrayFill(profit, 0, total, 0);  
  HistorySelect(0,TimeCurrent());  

  for(int n=total; n>0; n--)  
   {  
    if((ticket=HistoryDealGetTicket(n))>0)  
     {  
       price=HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket,DEAL_PRICE);  
       time=(datetime)HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_TIME);  
       symbol=HistoryDealGetString(ticket,DEAL_SYMBOL);  
       id=HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_POSITION_ID);  
       mg=HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_MAGIC);  
       ENUM_DEAL_TYPE type=(ENUM_DEAL_TYPE)HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_TYPE);  
       ENUM_DEAL_ENTRY in_out=HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_ENTRY);  
       if(price && time && symbol==_Symbol && mg==magic && in_out==DEAL_ENTRY_OUT && (type==DEAL_TYPE_BUY || type==DEAL_TYPE_SELL))  
        {  
         profit[n]=HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket, DEAL_PROFIT)+HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket, DEAL_COMMISSION)+HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket, DEAL_SWAP);  
         maxendinghere=MathMax(maxendinghere+profit[n], 0);  
         maxsofar=MathMax(maxendinghere, maxsofar);  
        }  
      }  
    }  
   return(NormalizeDouble(maxsofar, 2));  
}
`
The function of definition of the current profit earned by the expert.
`  
double Profit()  
 {  
  double price;  
  datetime time;  
  string symbol;  
  long type;  
  double profit=0;  
  ulong ticket;  
  long did;  
  long mg;  
  uint total=HistoryDealsTotal();  
  double pr[];  
  ArrayResize(pr, total);  

  HistorySelect(0,TimeCurrent());  

  for(int m=total; m>0; ir--)  
  {  
   if((ticket=HistoryDealGetTicket(m))>0)  
    {  
     price=HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket,DEAL_PRICE);  
     time=(datetime)HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_TIME);  
     symbol=HistoryDealGetString(ticket,DEAL_SYMBOL);  
     id=HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket, DEAL_POSITION_ID);  
     mg=HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket, DEAL_MAGIC);  
     ENUM_DEAL_TYPE type=(ENUM_DEAL_TYPE)HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket, DEAL_TYPE);  
     ENUM_DEAL_ENTRY in_out=HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket, DEAL_ENTRY);  
     if(price && time && symbol==_Symbol && mg==magic && in_out==DEAL_ENTRY_OUT && (type==DEAL_TYPE_BUY || type==DEAL_TYPE_SELL))  
      {  
       profit+=HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket, DEAL_PROFIT)+HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket, DEAL_COMMISSION)+HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket, DEAL_SWAP);  
      }  
    }  
  }  
 return(NormalizeDouble(profit,2));  
}
`
```